# how do you retain paragraph breaks and indentation from the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in this scenario, the user enters a bio about themselves, how do I retain spacing,etc...?

I tried the pre tag, but the width is fixed, so that's no good. I'm using rails, is there a better way to retain the paragraph formatting inserted by users, but not have the width fixed?

Comment: What do you mean by `the width is fixed`?

Comment: In the database, are the paragraphs stored with newlines encoded as `\n`? If so, do a string replace on `\n\n` to `<p>` followed by `\n` to `<br>` and just put the string into whatever container you like.

Comment: the position is fixed,  so there is no text wrap when you use a pre tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format), which returns text transformed into HTML using simple formatting rules. Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in `<p>` tags. One newline (\n) is considered as a linebreak and a `<br />` tag is appended. This method does not remove the newlines from the text.

You can pass any HTML attributes into html_options. These will be added to all created paragraphs.

Comment: Looks like what I need. Is this already installed in rails, or do I need a gem?

Comment: @NoobSter It is default in Rails, as a part of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html. You might want to check out some of the other methods in there, there are some good ones.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just to preserve line breaks entered by the user?
In that case you could use Rail's simple_format helper http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with javascript if you like. You'll need to replace all new lines with `<br />`

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    // Get div content
    string = $('#test').text()
    // Replace all carriage returns or new lines with an HTML line break.
    $('#test').html(string.replace(/(\r|\n)/g, '<br />'))

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s25vkwwu/)

Comment: saved me. only thing I changed was "window.onload = () => {" instead of the first line.